# How can I convert a TextArea to froalaEditor in a Button click using Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, dom, froala

I have an `TextArea` with its fields and I need to convert them to a `RichTextBox` and back on `Button` clicks using Angular2.

I am using the *FroalaEditor* plugin to get the `RichTextBox`. How should I process?

Comment: I improved some highlighting and the formulation of the question. And also the title.

Comment: Thanks for the edits

Comment: update the post with some code of yours